# Laptop's keyboard and display dead. HDMI out and usb keyboard works

Tags: laptop, keyboard, display, external-display

I have a HP ak008tx laptop. Its just over a year old. My first problem started after it accidentally got pulled off the table and onto the floor when someone walked through the power cable trap. -_-

After that i started getting the "/" key being held down automatically. It was very annoying, since it was intermittent and i would try to work through it. at one point it became too much so i pulled out the key and cut the strip under it. that solved it but now I'm missing the "/" key as well as the backspace key stopped working. But all was well and i continued working on it.

Now the keyboard and display stopped working randomly. It sometimes works but stops after while. If i connect the laptop to the TV through HDMI out and hook up a USB bluetooth keyboard i can work fine, no problem or interruptions. the keyboard backlight also doesnt work but the light on the capslock flashes when the system starts up and turns on and off when i toggle it on the external keyboard.

Thanks in advance, please help me guys. The TV is not mine and i cannot depend on it :/ I wonder what is the connection between the display ans keyboard ?:|

Comment: I suggest taking it to a professional repair service. Your "repairs" are doing more harm than good.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia yea I guess........ :/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is : Assume it will fail completely without warning.  Use the external keyboard, mouse, and monitor to move everything important off the laptop.  If you have files you use regularly, don't store them locally on the broken laptop, but store them on Google Drive, OneDrive, Box, or similar.  If you have a second PC, make that your primary PC.

Physically, the laptop might be repairable, but that's an open-ended question that SuperUser.com is not well suited for.  There's probably more problems and more symptoms that are going to show up as time goes on.

Unfortunately, warranty replacement probably won't work because it was damage instead of product issues (also, warranties are generally one year or less unless you intentionally buy the extended warranty).  Some companies sell accidental-damage-replacement plans, but you would have had to sign up for it intentionally.